# Navigation bar title not bold

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, fonts

When I'm in the storyboard, the navigation bar title is shown as bold in the Storyboard as default but when you run the app in simulator and device, it isn't bold. Annoyingly it isn't possible to change the font size from interface builder.

Below you can see the difference between what's shown on interface builder and the simulator.

Interface builder:
[image: Interface Builder]

Simulator:
[image]

I'm aware that I can change the font using something like this: `self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "YOUR-FONT-NAME-WEIGHT", size: 24)!`
That would be perfect but I want to keep the font to the default SF font.

Is there a workaround this? Any reason why this happens?

Comment: looks like a bug - have you tested on a device? Ultimately that's all you care about.

Comment: Yeah, it's on device as well. Check edit

Comment: Use this (translate to Swift): UIFont * font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize: 24.0f weight: UIFontWeightBold];

Comment: Are you doing something else in your code? I just did a quick test, and using 7+ for IB design mode, and 7+ Simulator, I get exactly the same font appearance (of course, the Simulator is 3x the size as the canvas in IB)... https://imgur.com/a/ReNN9

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this code in your `viewDidLoad` to change font size

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
    NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFontWeightHeavy)
]
```

For swift 4:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [
    NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.heavy)
]
```

Before in simulator it looks like 
[image]

And with that code, it looks like [image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `UIFont.systemFont` to get the default SF font.

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize:24, weight: .bold)]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4:**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.heavy)]
```